# Output python chart from virtual machine to host

Tags: matplotlib, virtual-machine, seaborn, virtualbox, spark-streaming

I am running Ubuntu VirtualBox without GUI. There is a PySpark streaming project. I want to output the streaming graph but obviously I realized (too late) that it would not be possible since I am using a no GUI VM. Is there a way to send the streaming chart (refreshed every n seconds) on the host environment? If yes, what would be the better way to do that? Appreciated.

Comment: host machine is windows? try xming to create virtual display for vm: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Comment: another way is to create a web server on host machine to receive chart images, host machine has a LAN IP, send http requests to it

Comment: @datdinhquoc Thx, yes Windows. I tried to install Xming by following this tuto https://geekvisit.com/putty-graphical-desktop-windows-x11-forwarding-xming/. At the end I tried to launch windows apps (not installed on the VM) via Putty but nothing happen. Also noticed `there are currently 0 clients connected` from Xming when double clicking on  Xming server icon. Is there a way without using Putty? Putty + VirtualBox + Xming seems a bit too much

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is actually a comment and I have less than 15 reputations but I think you can set up an X server and then use Xvnc? Actually, Linux can run GUI app without any WM or Desktop Environment but Xserver is required. See [this Stackoverflow post](https://superuser.com/questions/503343/gui-apps-without-a-graphical-desktop).

You can find more about Xvnc [here](https://tigervnc.org/doc/Xvnc.html)